# dart, why doesn't Timer.run() return a Future?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

Why doesn't `Timer.run()` return a Future? I am running some code inside the run() call which may throw an exception and if it doesn't return a future how can I add a `catchError()` on to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `Future.delayed` for this use case? This would give you a future that completes after a certain period of time. I'm guessing that's what you're trying to achieve by putting your code inside `Timer.run`.

You can find an example of how to use `Future.delayed` [here](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/futures-and-error-handling/).

You may also find [Dart docs about Future](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/Future.html) useful.